# Oracle Service Bus

Tags: download, osb

Is there any place where I can down load OSB 10gR3?

Thanks in advance,
Jani.

Comment: The recent version (11.1.1.3.0 at the moment) is here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/service-bus/downloads/index.html

Comment: Hi Thilo, Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: Hi Thilo, Actually I found recent version but I am after 10gR3.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen there is one available from http://edelivery.oracle.com , at least for windows.

not sure what platform you are after for.

if you go to edelivery, select win32, select 
"Oracle® Application Server 10g Release 3 (10.1.3) Media Pack for Microsoft Windows"
you will see
"Oracle Service Bus 10gR3 (10.3.1) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)   V16831-01   1.7G"
in the list

Answer (score 0):

OSB 10.3.1 win32 is available on mirror server: http://rapidshare.com/share/ADEB9A396E6835FD127A172BD3B22C88